# Sweetalert 2 - sorting Options for Select input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, select, sweetalert2

i have the following code :

```
this.getdata((params.....).then((data) => {

    var selectOptions = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        selectOptions[data[i].id_calc] = data[i].surname + " " + data[i].name;
    }
    console.log(selectOptions )
    Swal.fire({
        position: 'top',
        icon: 'warning',
        title: 'Attenzione',
        text: 'Select something',
        input: 'select',
        inputPlaceholder: 'Seleziona',
        inputOptions: selectOptions,
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'insert',
        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        cancelButtonText: 'cancel',
        inputValidator: (value) => {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                if (value > 0 && value != "" && value != undefined && value != null) {
                    resolve()
                } else {
                    resolve('Select something')
                }
            })
        },
        preConfirm: (value) => {
            callAPI(value) 
        },
        allowOutsideClick: () => !Swal.isLoading()
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
            console.log(result.value)
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'success',
                title: 'OK',
                text: 'ok!'
            })
        }
    })
})
```

So now i have something like this:

```
selectOptions[1535] : bob,
selectOptions[1536]: lucas,
selectOptions[3445]: laura,
selectOptions[6443]: andrew,
ecc
```

and the select input is sorted by selectOptions id,
but i need the select options to be ordered by the property "surename".

```
{
  6443: andrew,
  1535 : bob,
  3445: laura
  1536: lucas,
},
```

How can i achieve this?
I need the property "id_calc" to call a a funcion in the preConfirm section with the selected value (es if i select lucas i need to call the funcion with 1536 value)

My code works, but the options are not sorted by surename, any help?

p.s. sorry for my english!!

edit: the data recieved are already sorted but when i create the select option the become sort by the id

selecOptions is like

```
{
  225: "NOOK TOM ",
  467: "BITE ABEL ",
  479: "DOG MAX ", 
  1234: "ALAN DENIS",
...
}
```

i need

```
{
  1234: "ALAN DENIS",
  467: "BITE ABEL ",
  479: "DOG MAX ",
  225: "NOOK TOM ",
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before building the `selectOptions` array, sort the data recieved

```js
this.getdata((params.....).then((data) => {

    // sort incoming collection
    var sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => a.surname > b.surname);

    // build selectOptions with the sorted data
    var selectOptions = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < sortedData.length; i++) {
        selectOptions[sortedData[i].id_calc] = sortedData[i].surname + " " + sortedData[i].name;
    }

    // rest of the code unchanged

}
```